# Pass class object instance as parameter to another class object instance from main()

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I'm having issue on passing class object instance as parameter to another class object instance from `main()` function. Basically the problem is inside code below:

```
#include <something>
#include "another_thing"

class A
{
    void method1()
    {
        ;
    }

    void method2()
    {
        ;
    }
};

class B
{
    // Define an object of type class A
    A class_object;

    // Constructor
    B(A &passed_object)
    {
        class_object = passed_object;
        //other stuff here
    }

    void method1()
    {
        ;
    }

    void method2()
    {
        ;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A firstObject;
    B secondObject(firstObject);

    // Do something that changes A attributes;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that during `main()`'s execution some attributes of firstObject is changed but within passed_object inside class B I don't see this changes.

**EDIT**
Based on @HolyBlackCat tips, solved in this way:

Modified `A class_object;` in `A &class_object;`, removed `class_object = passed_object;` from constructor and changed constructor's `B(A &passed_object){}` in `B(A &passed_object) : class_object(passed_object){}`

Comment: If you want `class_object` to *reference* some object of type `A` (e.g. the one created in `main`), you need to make `class_object` a *reference*.

Comment: Also member initializer list is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the parameter of `B()` is a reference, simply passing `firstObject` to it indeed doesn't make a copy.

But you didn't make `A class_object;` a reference. When you assign to it in `B()`, you're making a copy.

You need to make the class field a reference: `A &class_object;`.

And since you have to *initialize* a reference with an object it should refer to, you're forced to use *member initializer list*:

```
B(A &passed_object) : class_object(passed_object) {}
```

Comment: Could you please modify my code in order to understand better? Thanks

Comment: @Francesco I already told you what changes you have to made, no? Change `class_object` to be a reference, and change `B()` accordingly.

Comment: Modified `A class_object;` in `A &class_object;`, removed `class_object = passed_object;` and changed `B(A &passed_object)` in `B(A &passed_object) : class_object(passed_object)`... It doesn't work

Comment: @Francesco What do you mean by *"doesn't work"*? Do you get a complation error, or changes made to `firstObject` don't affect `class_object`?

Comment: I don't see changes in A's attributes from B's object

Comment: @Francesco I can't reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb547e6a5e8ee874

Comment: Based on your example, I have to access `firstObject.x` within class B, not from `main()`

Comment: @Francesco It doesn't matter from where you access it. Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/871aceb5e152bec8

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. I found a little problem in other part of the code, but your answer resolves the main problem